# How to declare operation's generic return "T extends MyClass" type in UML?

Tags: generics, uml, covariance, return-type

I want to model in UML 2 methods with following singature:

**public <T extends MyClass> T doSomething();**

How I should rewrite it to UML ? 
I know that for concrete class it is simple: **+doSomething:com.x.y.z.MyClass** .

Answer (score 1):

UML [Parameterized Classes](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Parameterized+Class/) may be what you're looking for...

hth.

Comment: I know about parametrized classes but I don't think it is the right pproach for my case.

Comment: Because I want to have generic return type of one method, not to perametrize the whole class. Hmm, I'll edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if you didn't use the type `T` anywhere else (arguments of `doSomething`, or as type parameter to the class), do you actually *need* the `T extends MyClass` there---seems that stating `MyClass` will work just fine! So I'd go with @sfinnie here.

Comment: Yes, I know, that stating just MyClass will work. What I'm trying is to better describe/singalize that the required semantics that the return type could (in fact should) be different than just the MyClass - usually in child class it should return instance of the child class.

Comment: What you are describing is the general understanding of OO and the UML model anyway. I do not think that you need (and should) jump through extra-hoops. To the contrary, if you would be modeling a NON-OO setting, then you would have to think of some way to indicate this. You're not gaining much, at the cost of obfuscating your model.

Comment: I agree I do not gain much but still, but I do not expect much :). But there is hardly any obfuscation at all.